# Are normal infection cards still drawn after a player draws an epidemic card?

Tags: pandemic

I didn't see a clear explanation for this in the rule book so I wanted to double-check.

If a player draws an epidemic card during their turn do they still need to draw from the infection pile as normal? Or is that skipped since the epidemic card already added diseases somewhere?

Comment: Also see the [Common Pandemic Mistakes thread on BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/300287/common-mistakes), which covers this question, among others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You still perform the normal draws from the infection deck, after increasing the infection rate, infecting a new city with 3 cubes, and increasing the intensity of the infection.

> If a card is an Epidemic card, instead of taking the card in hand, refer to the rules for Epidemics, below. **After drawing the required cards, take on the role of the Infector.** See Playing the Infector on page 7.
>
> **Playing the Infector** - Draw cards from the Infection Draw Pile equal to the current Infection Rate and add one cube to the pictured cities, using a cube of the same color as each card. (Page 7)